# error on run execute file : dbrtl70.bpl missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, devart

I made an application with ADO Component and connect to Oracle with it, I don't have any problem when I run it in another machine.

But, when I use ODAC component and `TOraSession` and connect with it via *Direct Connect* and run it in another machine I faced to this error:

> The Program Can't Start Because dbrtl70.bpl is missing from your Computer. Try to re installing the Program to fix it

As I investigate, `dbrtl70.bpl` is Delphi package file in System32 folder.

I want to know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Check if you have any runtime packages selected. You must remove that settings or deploy the runtime files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and suggest that you have a 64 bit machine. You've copied the .bpl files into the 64 bit system folder (System32) where your 32 bit Delphi 7 program cannot see them. Put them in the 32 bit system folder (SysWOW64) instead and all should be well.

To learn more about the issue, read up on the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).

If you don't want runtime packages, and all your dependencies support being built without using runtime packages, then simply uncheck the use runtime packages option.

Comment: Dear, thank so much, but this is straight forward way and I Know it but I'm looking for better solution.

Comment: I honestly do not understand that comment. Perhaps you could explain what is wrong with this solution in your eyes.

Comment: I want Know is there another way to solve it, without copy some bpl file to destination Machnie?

Comment: Not if you want to link using runtime packages.

Comment: @user3214950 Are you happy now?

Answer (score 0):

My app was asking for a .bpl package when run on other machines.

Cancelling 'link with runtime packages' didn't solve it until I deleted the runtime packages listed in 'runtime packages'.  Then it was OK.